# How to convert strings to integers in haskell?

Tags: string, haskell, integer

I am working on implementing the RSA encryption system for a class or mine and to be able to implement it we obviously would need to convert strings to integers and then the reverse of that. Using basic level haskell can someone explain to me how this might be done. I have a function that will tell me the max length that a character code can be for your consideration as well.

Thank you everyone.

Comment: Can you please provide some examples on what conversions do you need?

Comment: What do you mean with convert? Like "123" -> 123 och something else?

Comment: I mean something like "Word" -> some number then some number back to "Word"

Comment: If you intend to encode the message directly with RSA, you're using RSA very incorrectly.

Comment: @WombatCombat: What if the resulting number is larger than the modulus? Then you can't encrypt it. Usually with RSA you use a hybrid approach. You use RSA to share a key and use that key to encrypt the message symmetrically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure exactly what you need, but if you are just trying to get a numerical representation of a `String`, you can use `Data.Char.ord` which will convert a `Char` to an `Int`. Then you can use `Data.Char.chr` to convert each `Int` back to a `Char`.

Using:

```
import Data.Char (ord, chr)

stringsToInts :: String -> [Int]
stringToInts = map ord

intsToString :: [Int] -> String
intsToString = map chr
```

you can:

```
Prelude Data.Char> let ints = stringsToInts "Hello world!"
Prelude Data.Char> ints
[72,101,108,108,111,32,119,111,114,108,100,33]
Prelude Data.Char> intsToString ints
"Hello world!"
```

You could then further process the list `ints` if that is what you need (and further modify `intsToString`.)

Comment: Pretty much exactly what I was looking for thank you! More input is welcome though guys!

Comment: This is what I tried with no luck though :(

str2Integer :: [Char] -> Integer
str2Integer = map ord

Comment: `ord` returns an `Int` which is not the same type as `Integer`. You should use `str2Integer = map (toInteger . ord)`. There is also a corresponding function `fromInteger`

Answer (score 0):

You may also use the `ByteString` module: convert a simple `String` into a `ByteString` with `pack` and then directly work with it as an array of bytes (`Word8`'s, if to be exact).